# How can I delete blocks from my pc. My storage is full due to blocks

Tags: storage

I have learned substrate some weaks ago, and due to generating of new blocks, my storage of pc is getting full.

Comment: What do you mean delete the blocks? Remove the unused data or prune the data?

Comment: Yeah How should I delete unused data

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying it out you should run the node with the following flag `--tmp`.

If you were using the `--dev` flag it should also delete everything on stop.

When you start the node, you should look for the following line:

```sh
2022-08-28 17:01:20  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/19/5tshxn412wx071h968j4s3s00000gn/T/substrate5R32Qo/chains/dev/db/full
```

If anything is being persisted, that's the path you need to clean.

I haven't run into that issue yet although I have a good amount of blocks stored. Are you sure the blocks are the issue? Note that the node itself can be more than 8GB

Comment: Yeah, may be due to nodes, my storage is getting full. Where nodes are getting stored?

Comment: It can also depend. If you are running `cargo build release` then the node is stored within the `/target/release/`. If you run `cargo build`, then it is being stored in the `/target/debug` directory. But once the node is compiled, it won't generate another executable with that size unless you are compiling it on different directories.

Comment: @TusharGoplani you can also run the following command to see if the node weights too much or not `du -sh ./*/`. My `/target/release` directory is about 8.6GB

Comment: Mine is 7.1GB ... But I have two drives in my laptop C and T. In C drive windows 11, applications and ubuntu desktop application installed. And Substrate node template, parachain template are in T drive. But at the time of running nodes..  storage is getting increased of C drive........ Almost 70-80 GB storage is getting covered of C drive

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your system and the CLI flags.

If you use the flag `--base-dir <path>` or `-d <path>`, check the `<path>`.

If you are on macOS, check the `~/Library/Application Support/<chain-name>`.

If you are on Linux, check the `~/.local/share/<chain-name>`.

Tips: if you run `./node purge-chain --chain <chain>`, it will show the path to the data.